# Query en mongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Estoy tratando de obtener un Query de la entidad Family en MongoDB que tiene la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo importante es el **estadoCuenta**, es una colección algo así como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener todas las familias que tienen por lo menos en algún ítem dentro del **estadoCuenta** el **donationFee**, es decir que exista un elemento dentro del **donationFee**, aveces solo el **donationFee es vacio = [];**

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que mirar que el tamaño de donatioFee sea mayor que 0 con $size y $gt. Te quedaría algo así:

```
db.collection.find({donationFee:{$size: {$gt: 0}} })
```